# Mule Vs ServiceMix in terms of spring support

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mule, apache-servicemix

I have been playing with `serviceMix` for quite a while now, it has some very interesting ideas and features (Modularity, hot deployment, lifecycle ...), the problem I've found with it is `spring` support, in the OSGI world blueprint is the standard for dependency injection (other than the dead `spring-dm`), which is a problem since our app is based on spring  ...

So I'm doing some research to see if there are other alternatives, I stumbled upon `eclipse Virgo` which from I can tell doesn't have a big community around it, plus it is based on `gemini blueprint` which has its limitations (`JTA`...)

I Am now looking into Mule which seems interesting, so I have some questions about it:

- Is it compatible with spring ? in other words is it easy to deploy a spring app and have Mule take care of creating the context ...
- Is there good support for JTA ?
- What about `hibernate` ?

any additional remarks/info is really appreciated

Thank you in advance

Comment: Take a look at Spring Boot instead, which also has great support with Apache Camel for integration needs.

Comment: Spring boot seems interesting, but I don't think it offers any thing new in terms of integration when compared to spring/camel, or Am I mistaken ?

Comment: No spring boot is the small/light runtime and then you add Camel on top of that for integration needs.

Comment: The most important thing is to use the right tools. I have heard developers using OSGI becaused they were seduced by the hot deployment, but never actually ended up using it. Today most apps have state in a database, and hot deployment is as simple as uploading a new Docker image, and telling you container service so migrate to the new version. If you use something like Amazons container service it is very easy - Most importantly you don't burden your developers with OSGI or other fancy technologies, that reduce their productivity.